# C++ wxWidgets - Creating wxDateTime from wxString

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a `wxString` that contains hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.  I'm trying to create a `wxDateTime` from this information.  I can either leave it in the format of `"%H:%M:%S.%f"` or I can grab the values individually.

My first thought was to use the `wxDateTime` constructor that takes in h, m, s, ms, however I can't find how to create a `wxDateTime_t` anywhere to pass into this.

`wxDateTime& wxDateTime(wxDateTime_t hour, wxDateTime_t minute = 0, wxDateTime_t second = 0, wxDateTime_t millisec = 0)`

I've also been looking a lot at `wxParseTime` where I would use the default `wxDateTime` constructor and then call this, but I don't know how to pass in the time as a `const wxChar*` correctly to this function.

`const wxChar * ParseTime(const wxChar *time)`

Can anyone give any insight on either of these ideas or give a better approach to this?

I've been getting my info through this site [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Additional info:
[wxDateTime::wxDateTime](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdatetime.html#wxdatetime),
[wxDateTime::wxParseTime](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdatetime.html#wxdatetimeparsetime).

Comment: I added links to the bottom of my question.

Comment: OK.  So what happens if you pass your string into wxDateTime::ParseDateTime()?  It should work well enough!

Comment: It takes in a const wxChar* and also it doesn't support the ms, I just posted an answer with a bunch of info I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that wxParseTime doesn't support milliseconds. Passing in `"%H:%M:%S"` is valid though.

Also I found this bit of information "The type wxDateTime_t is typedefed as unsigned short and is used to contain the number of years, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds." so it's possible to make unsigned shorts from the wxStrings using something like this.

```
unsigned long msec = 0;
token.ToULong(&msec);
```

This could be done for the hour, minute, second, and millisecond to pass into the `wxDateTime& wxDateTime(wxDateTime_t hour, wxDateTime_t minute = 0, wxDateTime_t second = 0, wxDateTime_t millisec = 0)` constructor to create the desired wxDateTime.

The route I went with was to use wxParseTime to update a wxDateTime object and then to set the milliseconds afterwards.  I got the current wxDateTime so the year/month/day would be preset.

```
token = lineTkz.GetNextToken(); // Next token is "%H:%M:%S"
const wxChar* constTime = token.c_str(); // Convert from wxString to wxChar*
wxDateTime dateTime = wxDateTime::Now(); // Get current datetime object
dateTime.ParseTime(constTime); // Update hours, minutes, and seconds from wxChar*
token = lineTkz.GetNextToken(); // Next token is milliseconds as wxString
unsigned long msec = 0; // Create unsigned long
token.ToULong(&msec); // Get value out of wxString and save into unsigned long
dateTime.SetMillisecond(msec);  // Update wxDateTime's milliseconds using set method
```

You can also verify you have a valid wxDateTime by using `bool isValid = dateTime.IsValid();` for error checking.

Another thing you can check is the return from calling wxParseTime

```
const wxChar* bad = dateTime.ParseTime(constTime);
```

wxParseTime "Returns NULL if the conversion failed, otherwise return the pointer to the character which stopped the scan.".

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this.

Comment: FWIW milliseconds are supported since more than 4 years in 2.9 in `ParseFormat()`.

Comment: So they're supported in ParseFormat() but not in ParseTime correct?

Comment: Correct, `ParseTime()` only tries the few most common formats and none of them includes milliseconds. Possibly it should try milliseconds too...